# Why doesn't &lt; convert to < while &gt; and other escape characters convert appropriately

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, soapui

I send a soap request through SoapUI and use `XSLT` to generate an `XML` response back. My response needs to look like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <TXLifeResponse>         
     <TransType tc="1201">General Requirement Order Request</TransType>
  </TXLifeResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am able to get this response from the below `XSLT`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:acord="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2"  
     xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:variable name="TransType_tc" select="//acord:TXLife/acord:TXLifeRequest//acord:TransType/@tc" />
  <xsl:variable name="TransType" select="//acord:TXLife/acord:TXLifeRequest//acord:TransType" />

  <xsl:template match="/">       
         <TXLifeResponse>       
          <xsl:element name="TransType">
            <xsl:attribute name="tc"><xsl:value-of select="$TransType_tc"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$TransType"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </TXLifeResponse>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I noticed an unexpected behavior. Before using `<xsl:element` and `<xsl:attribute>` tag, I did something like this in `XSLT`:

```
&lt;TransType tc=&quot;<xsl:value-of select="$TransType_tc"/>&quot;&gt;<xsl:value-of select="$TransType"/> &lt;/TransType&gt;
```

and the output received in `SoapUI` was:

```
&lt;TransType tc="1201">General Requirement Order Request &lt;/TransType>
```

Can anyone help me in understanding why `&lt;` was not converted but`&gt;` and `&quot;` did.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [syntax rules described in the XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax):

> The right angle bracket (`>`) may be represented using the string `&gt;`, and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either `&gt;` or a character reference when it appears in the string `]]>` in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.

So, this is legal:

```
<xml> > </xml>
```

...but wouldn't be in this case:

```
<xml> ]]&gt; </xml>
```

> To allow attribute values to contain both single and double quotes, the apostrophe or single-quote character (`'`) may be represented as `&apos;`, and the double-quote character (`"`) as `&quot;`.

So, this is legal:

```
<xml attr=" ' " />
```

...but wouldn't be in this case:

```
<xml attr=' &apos; ' />
```

Some escape encoder developers are overly cautious or it is easier to generalize representations because you don't need to know so much about the context in which you are escaping data.

Answer (score 2):

XSLT files are *also* XML files, so when you enter an escaped value like `&lt;` or `&gt;` it is understood as the `<` or `>` character. All characters are then escaped for the output XML as needed.

However, in the context of the output XML document it is not necessary to escape `>` or `"`, only `<`, so only the `<` is escaped.

You need to look at the XML spec for details, in particular the `CharData` production of an XML parser (which is where you are in the example you are giving). In XML `<` and `&` must *always* be escaped if they're intended to be character data, and `>` must be escaped if it's after `]]`.

`"` never needs to be escaped in a `CharData` context. Where you might need to escape `"` is if you are inside an attribute value (`AttValue` production) which is using `"` as the delimiter, e.g. `myattribute="this is a quote: &quot;"`.

Note that if you are generating XML using a tool that is ignorant of the XML parsing context (e.g., if you are constructing XML using strings), then the safest and easiest thing to do is to escape all three characters all the time. This is why you often see `&gt;` and `&quot;` escaped unnecessarily.

Comment: Can you please mention internet references to _However, in the context of the output XML document it is not necessary to escape > or ", only <, so only the < is escaped._ It will help in better understanding

Comment: I was not able to find any internet references, but I can confirm that > does not require escaping anywhere in XML, and `"` and `'` only require escaping to avoid having them mistaken for closing an attribute value, as in `<node greeting="&quot;Hello&quot;" />`.

Comment: @JLRishe, I have expanded the answer with a more thorough explanation. Refer to the full XML spec if you want even more detail. `>` does indeed need to be escaped *sometimes* in XML.

Comment: Ok, yes, I had read someone mention the `]]>` case while I was doing my search, but it seemed like an edge case that wasn't worth mentioning.

Comment: It's hardly an edge case if it produces an invalid XML document.